# How change the default title of a web page using QWebView

Tags: c++, qt

I am displaying a web page using the below code. But the title always shows as our company name(XYZ).

```
QString msg;
QWebView view = new QWebView();
view->page()->mainFrame()->setHtml(msg);
view->show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QWebView` title property seems read-only, and can only be set by using/changing a title tag in the HTML document.

However, the title of the window that pops up when the above code is run can be changed with `view->setWindowTitle()`, like with any Qt widget which is used as a toplevel window.